# Cards in a 5x5 grid- Probability of a diagonal of all hearts

Tags: probability

All the aces, 2’s, 3’s, 4’s, 5’s and 6’s, as well as the jack of diamonds are taken from a
regular deck of 52 playing cards, and then placed face up on a table in a 5 × 5 square
grid configuration randomly.

What is the probability that at least one of the diagonals in the array is all hearts?

I know that the probability of having all 5 hearts in a single row is 4!20!/24! but I am having trouble with this specific problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are only  6 hearts, right ?  So both diagonals can never be all hearts.

Comment: @Shailesh, they're asking for the probability that either diagonal is filled with hearts...not both. Can you show your work to get to 4!*20!/24!?

Comment: @lorek. OP has not said that i is the answer. I think the answer will be that multiplied by 12/25.

Comment: @Shailesh, I was not suggesting that 4!20!/24! was the answer he came up with for this problem. And I think yours is off by a bit, too. I'll post my solution once I get a response from OP.

Comment: @Lorek  please do .  I could be wrong.  I just did a few mental calculations.

Comment: @Shailesh, my original answer was lazy and incorrect. I have more confidence in the current version of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since both diagonals can't be all hearts at the same time, the desired probability is simply twice the probability that one diagonal is all hearts, and thus

$$
2\cdot\frac{\binom65}{\binom{25}5}=2\cdot\frac{6!\cdot20!}{25!}=\frac2{8855}\;.
$$

Answer (score -1):

There are two branches that must be considered. First, let's start with the center.  It has a 6/25 chance of being a heart.  Next, we'll traverse the diagonals.  The chance that the next spot we uncover is a heart is 5/24.  If it is a heart then we keep uncovering spots on that diagonal.  The chance that the next card is a heart is 4/23. If it is not a heart we still have a chance that the other diagonal is all hearts. So, there are two sub-branches here. If it is a heart then we have probabilities 3/22, and 2/21 until we uncover the entire diagonal.

There is a 19/23 chance that the third card uncovered is not a heart. If that occurs we switch to the other diagonal and require that all turns reveal a heart. We have probabilities 4/22, 3/21, 2/20, and 1/19 for this sub-branch.

After the center, there is a 19/24 chance that card we turned over is not a heart.  If that is the case then we switch to the other diagonal. The probabilities there are 5/23, 4/22, 3/21, and 2/20 until the entire diagonal is exposed.

So we have

```
P(total) = 6/25*(5/24*(4/23*3/22*2/21 + 19/23*4/22*3/21*2/20*1/19) + 19/24*5/23*4/22*3/21*2/20)
```

Recombining, we have

```
P(total) = 6/25 * (5!*20!/24! + 5!*19!/24! + 19*5!*19!/24!)
         = 6!/25! * (20! + 19! + 19 * 19!)
         = 6!/25! * (20! + 20!/20 + (19 * 20!)/20)
         = 6!*20!/25! * (1 * 1/20 + 19/20)
         = (2 * 6! * 20!)/25!
```

This is the same value as answer generated by my original solution. The original solution made some assumptions not made here.